# How to style FormControlLabel font size

Tags: material-ui

How do you set the in-line font size on a Material-UI FormControlLabel?  The below attempt does not work.

```
const styles: any = createStyles({
   formControlLabel: { fontSize: '0.6rem', 
   '& label': { fontSize: '0.6rem' } }
});

<FormControlLabel style={styles.formControlLabel}
  control={<Checkbox value="Hello" color="primary" />}
           label="World"
/>
```

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You could define the label as a Typography component and apply the style there:

```
<FormControlLabel 
    control={<Checkbox value="Hello" color="primary" />}
    label={<Typography style={styles.formControlLabel}>World</Typography>}
/>
```

UPDATE:

As per Saber's comment, newer versions should instead use:

```
<FormControlLabel 
    control={<Checkbox value="Hello" color="primary" />}
    label={<Typography className={styles.formControlLabel}>World</Typography>}
/>
```

Comment: It should be `label={<Typography className={styles.formControlLabel}>World</Typography>}` in recent versions.

Answer (score 10):

Use material box fontSize instead of giving external style.

```
 <FormControlLabel
        control={<Checkbox name="checkbox" />}
        label={
             <Box component="div" fontSize={15}>
                Small
              </Box>
        }
  />
```

Answer (score 10):

FormControlLabel exposes `typography` as prop. tested and works in Mui V5. https://mui.com/api/form-control-label/#props

```
<FormControlLabel
  componentsProps={{ typography: { variant: 'h3' } }}
/>
```

Answer (score 8):

In MUI v5 you could do it like this:

```js
<FormControlLabel
  label={
    <Typography sx={{ fontSize: 16 }}>
      Label Text
    </Typography>
  }
  control={<Switch />}
/>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use *overrides* section in theme.ts

```js
export default createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiFormControlLabel: {
      label: {
        fontSize: 14,
      },
    },
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option to achieve the same thing, but without the extra `p` that using `<Typography />` will give you (referencing MUI v4 as the post is from before v5, although I'm sure this solution will work there too).

By referring to the docs for the [FormControlLabel](https://v4.mui.com/api/form-control-label/#css) you can see the styles for the label can be modified with the `label` rule (kinda like you've tried to do already), however another approach would be to style the label by using [withStyles](https://v4.mui.com/styles/api/#withstyles-styles-options-higher-order-component)

```js
const StyledFormControlLabel = withStyles(() => ({
  label: {
    fontSize: '0.6rem',
  }
}))(FormControlLabel);

...

<StyledFormControlLabel
  control={<Checkbox value="Hello" color="primary" />}
  label="World"
/>
```

Comment: I used this, thanks. The simplest way.

Answer (score 1):

Another way may be to aim at Mui class directly e.g.:

```
.MuiFormControlLabel-label {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;

}
```